# shutil.move() borra una carpeta y no entiendo la razón

Tags: python, archivo, rutas

Tengo una serie de ficheros alojados dentro de otro fichero. Estos ficheros hacen referencia a varios platos de cocina y se alojan en un fichero llamado 'cocina'. Adjunto imagen:

[image: Ficheros con platos de comida]

Lo que me gustaría es mover todos los archivos que tienen el nombre "carnes-tipo_de_carne" a otra carpeta, alojada en el mismo sitio, que se llamará 'carnes'. Sin embargo, al utilizar `shutil.move`, no sé por qué pero el fichero con nombre "carnes-anade" desparece y solo aparece el contenido de este. Añado imagen para que se entienda:

[image: Tipos de carne]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, el fichero (al que he llamado 'carnes') contiene todas las carpetas referentes al tipo de carnes y dos archivos .txt. Estos dos archivos son los que estaban dentro de la carpeta "carnes-anade", y no entiendo el por qué esta carpeta ha desaparecido y solo han quedado sus archivos cuando lo único que he hecho ha sido mover las carpetas de sitio.

Añado el código que he utilizado.

```
import re
import os
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
    for dire in dirs:
        if re.findall(r'carnes-', dire):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root_path, dire),
                            os.path.join(root_path, 'carnes'))
```

Donde "root_path" hace referencia a la carpeta principal, o sea, a 'cocina', que es donde están alojadas las demás carpetas de platos de comida. Lo que he hecho es buscar mediante la función `re.findall()` todos los ficheros que tuviesen la string "carnes-" y los he movido a la carpeta "carnes", la cual se crea directamente una vez ejecuto el código.

¿Alguien sabe qué es lo que podría estar pasando?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) funciona bien sobre directorios existentes. Si el destino no existe, el [comportamiento será impredecible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502300/1545868), justo como te sucede.

Agregaré un par de variables para entender mejor, pero lo único que hay que hacer para resolver, es una comprobación de si el directorio destino existe:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
    for dire in dirs:
        if re.findall(r'carnes-', dire):
            src = os.path.join(root_path, dire)
            dst = os.path.join(root_path, 'carnes')
            if not os.path.exists(dst):
                os.mkdir(dst)
            shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy buena explicación y buenos enlaces :) Pensaba que como con la función se creaba el directorio de destino directamente no sería necesario crearlo previamente. Lo tendré en cuenta! Gracias de nuevo!